# How can I write my helper function's code more efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def partition(v, l):
    if l == []:
        return newList
    for i in l:
        if v == l[0]:
            newList[0].append(i)
            return partition(v, l[1:])
        else: 
            newList[1].append(i)
            return partition(v, l[1:])
newList = [[], []]

elementCounter= []
def countDistinct(l):  
    if l == []:
        return len(elementCounter)
    elif len(l)>0:
        return (elementCounter + [partition(l[0], l)[0]]) + countDistinct(partition(l[1], l)[0])
print(countDistinct([1,1,1,1, 2,3,4,5,8,8,8,8]))
```

When I try to recursively call partition through countDistinct, the recursion depth keeps exceeding the maximum limit. I've tried a lot of different ways of doing this and it won't work. Partition works well by itself, but how can I make it useable with countDistinct?

Comment: what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: it's supposed to count the number of distinct elements in a list. So it's supposed to return 6 in this case, because 1,2,3,4,5,8 are  our distinct numbers

Comment: So why not just `return len(set(l))`?

Comment: as @Aran-Fey said, I suggest using the set class, it will make it much simpler